# Print cursor.statement with parameters at error mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

In Python I use mysql connector to do queries, with seperate parameters like:

```
 cursor.execute("update tableA set a=%s,b=%s,c=%s", [1,2,3])
```

I know that when a query succeeded I can use:

```
print(cursor.statement)
```

but how can I get the actual query including parameters if I get an error?

So I would like to get:

```
"update tableA set a=1,b=2,c=3"
```

Answer (score 2):

You know that a query succeeded (at least technically - whether the result is what you expected is another problem) because it didn't raise any exception. So the obvious answer is: catch the exception and print your params from there:

```
myquery = "..."
try:
    cursor.execute("myquery", params)
except MySQLdb.MySQLError as e:
    # using the logging package would be better
    print("query '{}' with params {} failed with {}".format(myquery, params, e))
    # let the error propagate if you don't 
    # know how to / cannot handle it at this point
    raise
```

EDIT : if you want to get the exact query that was executed, then there's nothing that's [officially specified by the db api specs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). For MySQLdb, there's an undocumented yet public `Connection.literal(args)` method that you can use with your query and params, ie:

```
    sql = myquery % yourdbconnection.literal(params)
    print("query '{}' failed with {}".format(sql, e))
```

FWIW that's exactly how the executed query is built (cf the source for `MySQLdb.cursor.execute()`). Now while public (not prefixed with `_`) it's still undocumented so there's no garanty it will still work that way in the next release - and of course it's implementation specific so it might not work with any other db-api connector.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't exactly what I meant, I updated my question.